# Whirlybird part

Tags: repair, fans

The hinge of one of our whirlybird fans seems to be broken. Please see: https://www.youtue.com/watch?v=cN-aTwSkp44

What is the part necessary to? I heard that there is something called bearing kit for whirlybirds.

Could it be that one of these is what we need?

http://www.ampirevent.com/turbine-repeir-kits.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A repair kit solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the installation instructions that might be what you need.

follow the dissassembly/installation instructions and identify the failed parts, then confirm that they are all present in the repair kit.